# By what mechanism is back-emf induced in a railgun?

Tags: electromagnetism

I don't see what causes a back-emf in a railgun, because as the projectile moves along the rails, there is no change in field on any part of the projectile. Therefore, there shouldn't be any back-emf, right?

Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: The total area of the loop changes, the flux is area times field and so the flux changes.

Comment: @CuriousOne that makes sense. Could you remove this effect by moving the leads powering the rails along with the projectile?

Comment: @CuriousOne Actually I figured it out. When the bar moves along the rail, a lorentz force is induced on the charge in the bar, which creates an EMF opposite to the one that is pushing the bar.

Comment: You got it. The deeper reasons for EMF are relativistic, but you can consider a rather simple classical reason why EMF has to be there if you want to accelerate a mass: energy conservation. A constant current across the rails will lead to a constant acceleration $a$ i.e. $v(t)=at$. The kinetic energy of the projectile is then $E(t)=mv^2(t)/2=ma^2t^2/2$. The  power to accelerate the projectile is then $P=dE/dt=ma^2t$, i.e. it has to increase linear in time. Since $P=UI$ and $I$ is constant, the voltage across the circuit has to increase linear in time. There is no way around that.

Comment: @CuriousOne Haha, actually that's the reason I concluded that there must be a back EMF in the first place. I just wanted to figure out what caused it, and now I know.

Comment: Yep, it's nice that it's consistent, isn't it?

Comment: @CuriousOne Yeah. Now i'm curious about that relativistic EMF you mentioned...

Comment: Did you look on the site? I am sure we had questions about that. A good search term is also "homopolar generator", there should be a discussion about it under that topic.